# Why the text is not centered in mobile devices (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, alignment

[Website screenshot in PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM5zY.png)

[Website screenshot in the mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohFNd.png)

Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "boi.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="first">
    <h1>Hey!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>>
```

and this is the CSS code

```
body {
background-color: rgb(20, 18, 18);
}
.first {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 300px;
    color: white;
        text-align: center;        
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following css

```
.first
{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
.first h1
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: what is inline-block though?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain why this code fixes the problem on mobile when it was already working on desktop, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hey There are many solutions.

1. You can set width of element like the below code.
2. Or You can set the `display:` options into the element (for example, `display:contents`)

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(20, 18, 18);
}
.first {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 300px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;        
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    /* display: contents; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "boi.css">
<body>
  <div class="first">
    <h1>Hey!</h1>
```

Comment: why do I have to use display when there is **<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">**

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox especially in media queries for mobile size or desktop size

```css
.first {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 300px;
    color: white;
    width:100%;
       display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
        text-align: center;        
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "boi.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="first">
    <h1>Hey!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to make text center on vertical   align , you shold give a height to the div

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove your `margin-right: 300px;` - that's going to end up moving everything 300px to the left, thus leaving it very off-center on mobile.

Comment: yeah that i will try it